# Symfony form week picker

Tags: forms, symfony, date

I would like the equivalent of this:

```
<input type="week" ..>
```

with Symfony Form.

I try this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.date, {'attr': {'type': 'week'}}) }}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: In what way does it not work? Error messages? Unexpected values?  What form type is `form.date`. Add more details please.

Comment: Are you sure your browser is compatible with type=week ? What html code the form builder is generating ?

Comment: I got type two time : <input type="date" id="fiche_previsionnelle_debut" name="fiche_previsionnelle[debut]" required="required" class="form-control" type="week" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form theme. Supposing your form is named `foo` and your field is named `bar`, add this to a theme (inside your template or in a dedicated theme file):

```
{% block _foo_bar_widget %}
    {%- set type = 'week' -%}
    {{- block('date_widget') -}}
{% endblock %}
```