# week picker symfony form

Tags: html, forms, symfony

I would like the equivalent of this:

```
<input type="week" (...)>
```

with Symfony Form.

I try this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.date, {'attr': {'type': 'week'}}) }}
```

but it doesn't work, I get this :

```
<input type="date" (...) required="required" class="form-control" type="week" />
```

I use this type :

```
DateType::class
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony form week picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287340/symfony-form-week-picker)

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using `{'attr': {'type': 'week'}}` will only insert another type attribute. The problem lies with DateType::class. Although I looked into it but i am pretty sure that symfony currently does not support the `<input type= "week" />`. Or in laymens term there is currently no `WeekType::class` available in symfony.